# How does the python float function produce the value 0.041 from float(4.1E-2)?

Tags: python, function, floating-point

In other words... how to perform the arithmetic operation of scientific notation.
I've searched Youtube and other sites for an example that will help me understand the steps but I've recovered nothing.

Comment: Note that `4.1e-2` is already a float.

Comment: That might be true... However if you enter float(4.1E-2) into the Python console and run the code it returns the value 0.041.  I just need to know the steps used to receive the 0.041 value.

Comment: Well, my point was that if you enter `4.1e-2` into a Python IDLE/REPL you'd get `0.041` as well. :) The float function has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `0.041` is just another way of writing `4.1E-2`. `float` does nothing to it. What `4.1E-2` actually means is `4.1 * 10^-2`. [See what Wolfram Alpha says about it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4.1E-2).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking how the computer reads the characters “4”, “.”, “1”, “E”, “-”, and “2” and makes them into a floating-point number? Are you asking how Python treats its input and converts strings in inputs to various Python objects? Are you asking how the math to convert 41 times 10 to the power of −2 is performed to create .041? You need to clarify your question. Give other examples to compare to to show what you do and do not understand and which aspect you are asking about.

Comment: So yeah... I didn't understand how to convert the scientific notation to decimal notation myself.  Really need to refresh my basic math skills.  When I entered float(4.1E-2) into the Python Console it returned the value 0.041... however I see now that what I was really asking was how to perform the arithmetic operation of scientific notation. Thanks for helping clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You All... I apologize for any lack of clarity. So basically the E signifies scientific notation.  Therefore the value after the E is reproduced by 10 to the power of the value after the E.  To make it easier the E-2 adjusts the decimal two points to the left.

Answer (score 1):

4.1e-2 is a scientific notation is also know as exponential notation. Numbers in scientific notation must be entered in 'e' notation. For example, 1.234 x 10^40 is entered as 1.234e40 or 1.234E40.
Note that 1e0 = 1 x 10^0 and since anything raised to 0 is equal to 1, 1e0 = 1.

refer to the python [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#float) on float for more info

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you're asking, but `4.1e-2` is simply `float` written in [almost] scientific notation – mantissa with 1 digit before point + exponent.

Python VM parses this same way as any other numeric input. You may take a look at cpython [lexical analysis details for floats](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=float%20literal#floating-point-literals)